# DistanceFromLocation producing extremely large (incorrect) distance

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, location, distance

I've been having the hardest time trying to figure out why distanceFromLocation isn't calculting the correct distance for two CLLocations.  The calculated result is a number WAY larger than the actual distance but the two locations appear to be valid locations.

First of all, here are the two locations:

> LOCATION 1: <+44.56697840,
>   -69.55759810> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2010-12-13
>   21:12:03 -0500
>   LOCATION 2:
>   <+44.31400400, -69.79157000> +/- 0.00m
>   (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @
>   2010-12-13 21:12:03 -0500

And here is the code where Location1 and Location2 are being declared.  I've verified that these are the correct values, but I still can't figure this out

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] 
    initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue] 
    longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
    // CURRENT LOCATION (OR SEARCHED LOCATION)

double dLat = 0;
int tmpDistance = 0;
id returnId = nil;

id tmp = [featuredResults objectAtIndex:i];
CLLocation *newLocation2 = [[CLLocation alloc] 
    initWithLatitude:[[tmp valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue]  
    longitude:[[tmp valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]];

dLat = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation2];
```

The value that I'm getting for dLat is 330707027, which is way wrong.  Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: don't you want to calculate the distance from newLocation2?

Answer (score 0):

This test code based on the one in the question gives about 33,669 meters:

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] 
    initWithLatitude:44.56697840 longitude:-69.55759810];

CLLocation *newLocation2 = [[CLLocation alloc] 
    initWithLatitude:44.31400400 longitude:-69.79157000];

double dLat = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation2];

NSLog(@"distance = %f meters", dLat);

[newLocation release];
[newLocation2 release];
```

Output:

> distance = 33669.002406 meters

Perhaps you are logging dLat using something other than `%f`?